# nsis drag and drop for nsdialogs

Tags: draggable, nsis, nsdialogs

i want to drag and drop the window by image , i mean :  you hold the  mouse1 on main image or on a little label to get drag and drop on the window(left right , up down ) .
[image]

i have already tried code like this:

```
System::Call "user32::GetCursorPos(lp$MoveSize)"
System::Call "user32::ScreenToClient(i$HWNDPARENT, lp$MoveSize)"
System::Call "user32::SendMessage(i$HWNDPARENT, i$WM_SYSCOMMAND, i$SIZE, i0)"
```

but these functions  is not talking to me.
seem to works with old file "nsWindows.nsh"

```
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN} ${HTCAPTION} $0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx @ Anders , working example .

```
 RequestExecutionLevel User
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT GuiInit
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

 


Section
DetailPrint Hello
Sleep 1234
SectionEnd


Function GuiInit 
MoveAnywhere::Hook # MoveAnywhere.dll
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [MoveAnywhere plug-in](https://forums.winamp.com/forum/developer-center/nsis-discussion/306972-how-to-move-a-window-without-a-title?p=4179935#post4179935).

Comment: second hard way to do that , must be something like that = WM_NCHITTEST . calling this func.

Comment: The plug-in posts WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN.

Comment: can in be inserted in nsdialogs ?. like before or after func ?   ${NSD_CreateBitmap} 0u 0u 555u 309u ""

Comment: i have found : the image in nsdialogs must be set to " ws_disabled" flag

Comment: and for the "Label" - it is unresolved.